# Is CSRF protection required for GET, which only obtains data from DB?

Tags: java, json, spring, security, csrf

[response in another topic](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/115794/should-i-use-csrf-protection-for-get-requests)

> GET requests are to be used for idempotent requests, or requests that do not change state. These requests do not need to have anti-CSRF tokens.

1. Is CSRF protection required for GET, which only obtains data from DB?
2. If yes, will it be secured with "accept json"

   @RequestMapping(value = "/stub", method = RequestMethod.GET, 
   headers="Accept=application/json")

   public Object getStub() {

   return stub;

   };

Comment: Can someone change the data in the DB?

Comment: no, only select queries.

Comment: Only select queries through GET, or only select queries **ever** and **anywhere**.

Comment: only select with this GET and all filters before. Other GETs are not in our topic.

Comment: Data in databases tends to change over time. If it's extremely long lived data then using GET may be appropriate. But if it generates dynamic results then GET is probably not appropriate.